# Android: Setter in Fragment & get String in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm getting a `String` from a my `MySQL` database which works fine. After I got the data I was trying to set the data in a Setter and fill a get the data in my RecyclerAdapter to output it as a list but it wont work. 
The only thing that works is getting data from my db and set the setter after that it wont work dont know why.

```
public ArrayList<NewsData> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<NewsData> newsData = new ArrayList<NewsData>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            NewsData nd = new NewsData();
            nd.setTitle(json_data.getString("title"));

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nd.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            newsData.add(nd);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return newsData;
}
```

Here I am getting the Data of my database and test if it works by making the data as a Toast and that works fine.

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView holeText;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_cView);
            holeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context = itemView.getContext();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_cardviewhome, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This is my adapter I already tried some things but they won't work maybe one of you guys could help me here. So I wanna add the data of the `MySQL` to the `RecyclerView`. (The data which i got in "`parseJSON`")

My Adapter is nearly Empty as the moment as I delete everything that was wrong and dont work

I hope you can understand my english it's not very good. But all in all thanks for trying to help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should pass the newsData as a parameter to the adapter constructor. Inside onBindViewHolder, you could set the TextViews information by getting from the item. Example:

```
    public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NewsData> newsData;

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter (ArrayList<NewsData> newsData, Context context) {
       this.newsData = newsData;
       this.context = context;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView holeText;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_cView);
            holeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context = itemView.getContext();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_cardviewhome, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewsData thisNewsData = newsData.get(position);

        holder.itemTitle.setText(thisNewsData.getItemTitle());
        holder.holeText.setText(thisNewsData.getHoleText());
    } 

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsDataArray.size();
    }
}
```

If something is off, please adjust accordingly and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey, first thanks for your answer and that you are trying to help me. Sorry for the question but what is meant with "newsDataArray" in the getItemCount. I got no Object that is called newsDataArray. Again sorry im quite new to this theme.

Comment: It is a placeholder name for the array that contains the NewsData objects, passed as parameter when creating the Adapter in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the initial list to the adapter:

```
private ArrayList<NewsData> newsData;

public HomeRecyclerAdapter (ArrayList<NewsData> newsData) {
   this.newsData = newsData;
}
```

Fetch new data from your database in an `AsyncTask` in `doInBackground()`. There you can parse the data and create your objects. In `onPostExceute()` you can modify the data of your adapter. For example you add this to your adapter and call it in `onPostExceute()`:

```
public void add(NewsData data) {
  this.newsData.add(data);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```